Power Apps Calendar Colour Change based on total
I've built a calendar and everything works.
If I have a date assigned in Sharepoint, a coloured bar appears on the calendar date. If I click in that date I can show the filtered projects that have been assigned to that date.
However....
What I would like it to do is change colour if the Duration column in total exceeds 5 lets say.
Example 1
Date 8/21/2024
Project 1 Duration = 3
Project 2 Duration = 4
Duration total = 7 
Colour RED

Example 2
Date 8/21/2024
Project 1 Duration = 3
Duration total = 3
Colour GREEN

I've test this out in a text box
"All Points: " & Sum(Filter('Calendar Booking Form', Date = "8/21/2024"), Duration)
And this came back with the total 10 (Which is correct).
So I moved over to the calendar object fill.
If(DateAdd(_firstDayInView, ThisItem.Value) = Date(2024,8,21),RGBA(238, 75, 43,1),RGBA(186, 202, 226, 1)) 
I tested this out next and I got a light blue and all others red. I didn't mind this as again, it worked as it isolated the one I wanted.
But I can't for the life of me get it to go through each date and colour those with a collective total of above 5 RED and the all the others that are visible to be another colour (GREEN for example)
If(Sum(Filter('Calendar Booking Form', DateAdd(_firstDayInView, ThisItem.Value), Duration) <= 5, RGBA(186, 202, 226, 1), RGBA(238, 75, 43,1))
And it doesn't like this at all. I don't know how to get it to go through each day, check the Duration and if it's greater than 5 change the colour otherwise be another colour.
